# ¿Cómo comparar dos archivos en PHP?

Tags: php, fileupload

estoy haciendo subida de archivos en PHP ($_FILES), y antes de que me lo suba al servidor, quisiera que me compruebe si el archivo es una copia, por la cual hice lo que hice es que al insertar los datos se me cree un codigo md5 que sera el documento y sera unico en cada documento, imagen, video, y audio, ya que lo que hace es leer el archivo con file_get_contents() y después le crea un md5, hasta ahí bien pero, lo que quiera es que después del upload, me haga un filtro con if, que si el md5, con la hora actual, que acabo de subir es igual a otro md5 que se ha subido, significa que es el mismo archivo (con snombre diferente), y me elimina el archivo con la hora mas reciente.

Lo que no acabo de saber es como hacer este if, por ahora he hecho esto:

```
                $conexion = new mysqli("privado","privado","privado","privado");
                if (!$conexion) {
                    die("Error al conectar con la DB: ".$conexion->connect_error);
                }
                $ruta = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/plugins/mensajeria/archivos/chat_do/videos";
                $url = $ruta."/".$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$url);
                date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
                $fecha = date("d/m/Y");
                $hora = date("G:i");
                $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje_text'];
                mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$mensaje);
                $name_file = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                $size_file = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
                $type_file = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
                $url1 = file_get_contents($url);
                $md5 = md5($url1);
                $enlace = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/plugins/mensajeria/archivos/chat_do/videos/".$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                $insertar = "INSERT INTO chat_do (md5,Clase,Mensaje,Multimedia,NombreArchivo,TamanoArchivo,TipoArchivo,Fecha,Hora) VALUES ('".$md5."','1A','".$mensaje."','".$enlace."','".$name_file."','".$size_file."','".$type_file."','".$fecha."','".$hora."')";
                $mostrar = "SELECT md5 FROM chat_do WHERE Fecha != '".$hora."'";
                $result = $conexion->query($mostrar);
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                if ($md5 != $mostrar) {
                    if ($conexion->query($insertar) === TRUE) {
                        echo "1 video";
                    }else{
                        echo "error video";
                    }   
                }else{
                    unlink($url);
                    echo "archivo_copiado";
                }
```

El problema es que no se porque no funciona, creo que es `$md5 != $mostrar`, lo que esta mal. No se. Lo que quisiera hacer es que me diga si el $md5 es igual al primer dato de la DB md5, sino al segundo, al tercero... así consecutivamente hasta que consida con uno y me salte el `else`. La caso es que tiene que ser automático, no puedo hacerlo manualmente, sino no funcionará.

```
                if ($md5 != $mostrar) {
                    if ($conexion->query($insertar) === TRUE) {
                        echo "1 video";
                    }else{
                        echo "error video";
                    }   
                }else{
                    unlink($url);
                    echo "archivo_copiado";
                }
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si los archivos son muy grandes te va a consumir mucha memoria en el servidor.

Comment: Aparte el formato de codificacion del archivo puede dar comparaciones invalidas.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas es hacer una [verificación de redundancia cíclica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verificaci%C3%B3n_de_redundancia_c%C3%ADclica) (CRC checksum). Es un ID hash que se genera a partir del contenido del archivo y sirve para verificar la integridad de los datos. Si los archivos son iguales deben generar el mismo ID checksum. [md5_file](https://php.net/manual/es/function.md5-file.php) o [sha1_file](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sha1-file.php) puede servirte para la comparación.

```
if(md5_file("carpeta/archivo.odb") == md5_file("carpeta/archivo2.odb")){
      echo "archivo copiado, los archivos son iguales";
}else{

  //funciones para subir el archivo al servidor

}
```

Answer (score 0):

He probado de hacer lo que tu dices cardeol, pero no se porque no me lo ejecuta:

```
if ((md5($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']) == md5($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/plugins/mensajeria/archivos/chat_do/videos/".$_FILES['archivo']['name'])) || (md5($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']) == md5($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/plugins/mensajeria/archivos/chat_do/audios/".$_FILES['archivo']['name'])) || (md5($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']) == md5($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/plugins/mensajeria/archivos/chat_do/imagenes/".$_FILES['archivo']['name'])) || (md5($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']) == md5($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/plugins/mensajeria/archivos/chat_do/documentos/".$_FILES['archivo']['name']))) {
    echo "archivo_copiado";
}
```

Que puede estar pasando? Vi si tengo algún error de sintaxis y no tengo ninguno

Gracias de antemano

Comment: si esto no es una respuesta no uses esta zona para colocar aclaraciones, dale editar a tu pregunta y añade lo nuevo

Answer (score -1):

La solucion es utilizar la funcion `strcmp(var1,var2)` que compara dos `string` a nivel binario